# Mixing @Value of map and fallback value in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Trying to get an optional map in a config, I tried

```
@Value("#{${my.prefix.mymap} }") Map<String, Integer> mymap
```

that works with `my.prefix.mymap={a=3, b=4}` in the property file and fails if not (defined in a property file)

Sounded neat so far.

But

```
@Value("#{${my.prefix.mymap : { a : 1, b : 2 } } }") Map<String, Integer> mymap
```

or

```
@Value("#{${my.prefix.mymap ?: { a : 1, b : 2 } } }") Map<String, Integer> mymap
```

give 1 and 2 as values, whatever is defined in the property file.

I wonder if I missed a magic syntax, or that I was hoping too much.
Is that a bug (from me or the framework) or just a frustrating lack of feature ?

Spring is 6.0.11 here

[Edit 1]

Tried, after receiving first comment :
`@Value("#{${my.prefix.mymap} ?: { a : 1, b : 2 } }") Map<String, Integer> mymap` but got `Could not resolve placeholder`.

Also tried, then : `@Value("#{${my.prefix.mymap:null} ?: { a : 1, b : 2 } }")` but got the same problem when defined in the property file : I get the default value.

[Edit 2]

Tried
`@Value("${my.prefix.mymap : #{ {a:1, b:2} } }") Optional<Map<String, Integer>>`
and got :
`No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.String]`
when `my.prefix.mymap={a:2,b:3}` is in the properties file

[Edit 3]

Got same answer when `my.prefix.mymap=#{{a:2,b:3}}` is in the properties file, too.